# What does the 'size of database' parameter do when creating a SQLite database?

Tags: javascript, sqlite

When creating a SQLite database with javascript, there is a size of database parameter.

`var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);`

- What does the size of database parameter do... does it limit the max 
  size that the database can hold?
- What happens if you exceed that size?
- What is the max that number can be set at?

Comment: Seems like it will be fine: https://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/#databases

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html look at the Maximum Database Size

Comment: @zerkms yup, saw that. doesn't say if it's a hard limit, or what happens when the size is exceeded.

Comment: @kylex "This allows a site that is aware that it will try to use hundreds of megabytes to declare this upfront, instead of the user agent prompting the user for permission to increase the quota every five megabytes." --- I believe this means it will continue growing.